# Correct Use of UML Icons for Source Control in Continuous Delivery Modelling

Tags: version-control, uml

Working on a proposal diagram of a Continuous Delivery Model, and am looking for a way to represent Source/Version Control in the diagram. I don't see a specific icon for Source/Version Control in yED graph editor, and google searches don't seem to be helping much. I can't use the same icon as database since I also have a number of databbase objects in the same model as well.

Is there a generally accepted or official diagram shape/icon/whatever for source control (git, svn)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no icon for version control defined in UML.

(*Nor is there one for a database for that matter.*)

You can download the full specification of UML on the [OMG website](https://omg.org/spec/UML).